# How to add an empty string as the first element of an existing array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I am merging array values. This is my code and it works fine.

```
function photomag_image_size() {
    $image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    return array_merge($image_sizes, array('full',));   
}
```

[image]

Now I want to add another element holding an empty string in the first position of the array and also keep `full` as the last element. I want the first dropdown option to be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with  **array_unshift()** php function  check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)
like this

```
   $queue=array_merge($image_sizes, array(
        'full',
       ) );
    array_unshift($queue, " ");
    return $queue;
```

Comment: Sorry I was off the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `array_unshift` or just merge like you did with `full` like this:

```
function photomag_image_size() {
    $image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    $image_sizes = array_merge(array(""), $image_sizes);
    return array_merge($image_sizes, array('full') ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_merge` again

```
$temp = array_merge($image_sizes, array('full'));
return array_merge(array("first") , $temp);
```